# MongoDB map reduce upsert

Tags: mongodb

I don't know if I am using the right way of saying what I need, through the term of "upsert". I am new to mongoDb and what I would need, is this. I have a SOURCE collection and a TARGET collection. The SOURCE collection keeps changing (same structure, new data). I am running a mapreduce on the SOURCE to the TARGET, but I need to keep updating, not replacing the data existing in the TARGET. For example, if I have 3 subdocuments in the TARGET and 2 new subdocuments resulting from the SOURCE, I need to obtain 5 subdocuments in the TARGET. Is this achievable? If it is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fantastic concept here called a 'rereduce'.

Essentially it allows you to run the reduce function on an existing collection.

This is the most helpful bit:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/

Essentially you need to do:

```
db.mycollection.mapReduce(myMapper, myReducer, {out:{reduce:'targetCollection'}});
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is the closest thing to what I need, but I still lose old sub-documents.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you don't. I use this technique to keep a document of user actions. Each day we look at the total events and then mapreduce these on top of the user actions document. Users who haven't interacted for months are still in the database (and need to be wiped!)